# Measurement of properties of custom classifying algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

I am interested in measuring my classifier algorithm. Therefore I look for something similar to `ClassifierMeasurements`, where I can put my predictions result and true labels and get the accuracy  and `AreaUnderROCCurve`.